# Template explicit instantiation in header

Tags: c++, templates

I know that it's possible to declare a template in the header and its definition in a source file as long as I declare in advance the parameters it will be instantiated with. My question is: will putting the explicit instantiations in the .h file create problems? It seems to work but I've always seen people putting them in the source file, not in the .h

What I have in mind is the following

.h file

```
class foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void do(const T& t);
};

template<> void foo::do<int>(const int&);
template<> void foo::do<std::string>(const std::string&);
```

.cpp file

```
template <int>
void foo::do(const int& t)
{
    // Do something with t
}

template <std::string>
void foo::do(const std::string& t)
{
    // Do something with t
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile this?

Comment: You are creating defnitions with that, and you will run into the same problems as with other kinds of definitions in headers.

Comment: @PlasmaHH what I'm curious about is why the definition code can be in the source for the explicit specialization, why isn't an explicit instantiation required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called explicit specializations.  Explicit instantiation is something else.

Putting those declarations in the header file is fine, and a very good idea.  When compiling other source files, you want the compiler to know not to generate those specializations using the primary template.

Your syntax in the *.cpp file is wrong, though.  The definitions should be more like the declarations:

```
template <>
void foo::do<int>(const int& t)
{
    // Do something with t
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And how come I can define those routines in the cpp file? I thought it was only possible with explicit instantiation (that I don't see here since you cleared my doubt)