# Same non-template member function definition for multiple types of template class specilization

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++17

Is it possible that some types of specialized class share one non-template member function definition of a declaration, some types of specialized class share another non-template member function definition with the same declaration in class as above, and the function definitions is in cpp not hpp?

for example: I have a template class *A* with non-template member function *p*

```cpp
template <typename T>
class A {
    void p() {
        print("food.\n");
    }
};
```

And I have 4 types: banana, apple, fish, steak to specialize the class *A* for usage in main.cpp:
if A is specialized as *A<banana>*, *A<apple>*, *p* print "fruit",
if A is specialized as *A<fish>*, *A<steak>*, *p* print "meat".

I would not write 2 times of version: print "fruit" 2 times of version: print "meat" 2 times. Meanwhile, since which type of specialized class print what text has been concrete, is it possible that the 2 versions of *p* definition could be write in cpp files to reduce cost of compilation?

Comment: Which C++ version?

Comment: C++ 17 or above.

Comment: What you have is a typical schoolbook example for using *inheritance*, not specialization. Did you write this question because of curiosity and experimentation, or do you have an underlying problem that you need to solve? Curiosity and experimentation are fine drivers of learning more, but please say that inside the question itself. If you have an underlying problem then please ask about that directly instead.

Comment: It is because my origin case is too complicated. It is a compiler for NPU, I have about 10 types of architecture. It has 3 layers of compiling, the first layer has about 20 operators, many of them have diverse implementations for different architecture, but groups of architectures may share same operator implementation. Yes, inheritance is classic and typical for the case, but my second stage and third stage are also architecture specified, how could I control the 3 stages with same pattern of class layout if I need keep the type from very beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `if constexpr` to check types and print accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Fish {};
struct Steak {};
struct Banana {};
struct Apple {};

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    void p() {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, Apple> || std::is_same_v<T, Banana>)
            std::cout << "Fruit\n";
        else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, Fish> || std::is_same_v<T, Steak>)
            std::cout << "Meat\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    A<Fish> fish;
    A<Apple> apple;

    fish.p();
    apple.p();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive description. Is it possible to write p in cpp file? So far I think the definition of function p must be together with declaration of class A

Comment: Yes, but you may face some compilation errors since A is a template class. For that, from what I remember, we need to provide forward declarations of all possible template specializations.

Comment: Read this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl

Comment: Explicit specialisations as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145632/template-explicit-instantiation-in-header) would allow to move the definitions into a cpp file. That adds yet another advantage: `A<YetAnotherType>` will then fail to compile as long as the template argument is not considered in the list of specialisations (which should not be extended before that type has been added to `p` function...).

Comment: @Aconcagua doesn't that create hard to read linker errors given it's templates?

Comment: @JimmyT. Well, indeed, it would be the linker having to detect the issue then. Probably better alternative would be a corresponding `static_assert`. Moving to .cpp file was explicitly asked in the question, though, thus mentioning. Then again the template functions might call one or more non-template helper functions residing in the .cpp file, but specific requirements for are unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance might help you out in this case:

```
class Fruit
{
protected:
    void p() { /* ... */ }
};

class Meat
{
protected:
    void p() { /* ... */ }
};

// general case left unimplemented not to allow arbitrary instantiations
template <typename T>
class A; 
// (alternatively you might provide a default implementation handling the unspecific case)

template <>
class A<Apple> : Fruit
{
public: using Fruit::p;
};

template <>
class A<Fish> : Meat
{
public: using Fruit::p;
};
```

If it is meaningful to provide a *public* type hierarchy is up to you to decide, you might then add a generic root `class Food` with a pure virtual `p` (then public, of course) while you'd let `Fruit` and `Meat` have `override`ing `p`. This would e.g. allow to add the different types of food to a container, but you need to use (smart?) pointers for to avoid object slicing.

Public inheritance with public `p` in the base classes could be applied for convenience only, too, for not having to specify the `using` clause – though convenience for the *implementer* of types usually leads to less clean code in the end...